# installing 17.04, it's stuck at 66% of "installing grub"

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 17.04

my setup consists of:

AMD a4-4000 CPU
a85x chipset
4GB RAM

On the partitioning steps, I tried:
- "setup entire disk with LVM"
- "setup entire disk without LVM"

I was previously running 16.04 on this setup.

I found a similar discussion to mine (click [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/os-prober/+bug/1663645)) but reading the it, the issue should've been fixed when 17.04 was released officially.

Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I have seen some systems error on 30_uefi-firmware which is run immediately after 30_os-prober. can you verify which step it hangs on?